# which one is $A$ in $X = S^1 \times D^2$ ? Hatcher Problem $16$ chapter $2$

Tags: algebraic-topology

I have some confusion in  the  Allen Hatcher book diagram page no :$39$  and $Q.16$  -$(c)$

$X = S^1 \times D^2$  and $A$ the circle  shown in the figure [image]

**My confusion**:   which one is $A$ ?

**My thinking** :  I think that the first one is  $A$ because $A$ is a circle and $2$nd figure is not $A$, because $2$nd $A$  does not look like a circle

Comment: Please write an *informative* title.  Yours could apply to questions in nearly every branch of mathematics.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork i edited

Comment: It is the $A$ you have labelled 2) as shown in Hatcher's figure. It may not "look" like a circle, but it is topologically a circle linked round itself

Comment: okay @MichaelCohen..

Comment: Then  why  one  circle  is  given in the  upper part diagram?@MichaelCohen

Comment: sorry in the upper part of the diagram

Comment: I think that's just to make the diagram look clearer.. Otherwise it would look like a flat annulus rather than a torus. Hatcher clearly indicates what he means by $A$, and it is certainly a topological circle. Not all circles are round!

Comment: If I remember correctly, this exercise is found in chapter 1 section 1, as opposed to chapter 2?

Comment: @SteveS I have not read the chapter $1$

Comment: @jasmine you're referring to chapter 0. Page 39 is in Chapter 1.

Comment: oh yes @SteveS you are right .This excerise  is  found in chapter $1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A$ is the "self-linking" longer curve, embedded in the solid torus.  It is not the short, "round" curve, on the boundary of the solid torus.